# How to save Windows command line input?

Tags: windows, command-line

I find myself re-writing the same commands in the Windows Command line.  For example, I always use "cd" to move the same folder every time I use the computer. If I close the command window I must do it all over again.

Is there a way to save the commands into a text file and then load that text file into the command window?

Comment: Sounds like too general a question. For that specific "cd" problem, you could make a shortcut to the command prompt with the "start in" field filled out the folder you always use. Or if you have the folder open you can shift-right-click and choose "open command window here". Or if you really want you can make batch files.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Creating a short-cut with start in sounnds like it has potential... How do I create a shortcut on the desktop?

Comment: You can create a shortcut to either `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` or more explicitly something like `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and then in the shortcut properties (right click -> properties) there is a section called `Start In` which designates which folder the executable boots up in. If you wanted to start in the root you could put in `C:\ `

Answer (score 1):

This will show the history of commands.

DOSKEY /history

You could then create a macro for all of the commands that you continuously are running.

**EXAMPLE:**

> A macro called `d' to run dir/w DOSKEY d=dir/w
>
> DOSKEY macros are only saved for the current session.
>
> The command:
>   doskey /macros >macros.cmd
>
> Will list all current macro definitions
>   into macros.cmd, edit this file and place DOSKEY at the start of each
>   line. Then to restore all the doskey macros setup in the current
>   session at a later date, run macros.cmd

Reference Used:
https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html

Comment: I thought that only showed history on a per session basis? If you close the window it resets.

Comment: Hi, I put DOSKEY/history at the command prompt.  It showed my old commands but when I closed/reopened the command window it did not give the old commands.

Comment: Press F7 also shows the command history.  To save all the commands, you might have to save all the history to a file and keep appending it.  I am not sure if there is something already available that you could save all the history of all the sessions without saving it to a file.  Also refer to http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/commandpromptoptions.mspx?mfr=true